# how to make publish file in window form application with local .mdf file that work on any other pc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

i make simple curd operation with local Database.mdf file and when i make publish it .exe file work fine on my developement laptop but when i move to any other laptop it give me this error.
[image]

and my connection string look like this
cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

please help me if any one face this type issue in window form application thanks

Comment: Quote: *Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) on the target machine.

If you are looking for a truly self-contained database that can be shipped with your application and run "as-is" without any remote servers or specific setup, you could try [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

LocalDB is not self-contained.

Comment: Thanks, I used SQLite instead of localDb. It was helpful, thank you.